# How to find all local user accounts in chef

Tags: user-accounts, user-profile, chef, chef-solo

Using opscode chef, is there a way to find or loop over all user accounts?

I need to create a configuration file in each users home directory.  I do not want to loop over any directory structure for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All users on the system are automatically detected by ohai when Chef runs, and available in the `node['etc']` attribute space. Users are `node['etc']['passwd']`. You can iterate over this like a hash. You can exclude "system" or "precreated by packages" by comparing whether a user's numeric ID is over whatever is defined in your systems /etc/login.defs UID_MIN.

Example usage in a recipe to create a config file that you have stored in the cookbook, a different file for each user.

```
node['etc']['passwd'].each do |user, data|
  if data['uid'].to_i > 1000

    cookbook_file "#{data['dir']}/custom_config" do
      source "#{user}_custom_config"
      owner user
      group data['gid']
      mode 0644
    end

  end
end
```

Replace "custom_config" with whatever your config file is named.

Comment: Foodcritic dictates you should put that conditional inside the `cookbook_file` declaration: `cookbook_file ... do only_if { data['uid'] > 1000 } end`

Comment: @sethvargo I have issues with FC023, as reported here: https://github.com/acrmp/foodcritic/issues/51

Comment: Nice answer. I was trying to figure out if Chef can find the `home`/`users` directory, which is conveniently in that provided `data['dir']` parameter.

Comment: To clarify, I did this: `home = node['etc']['passwd'][node['nodejs']['user']]['dir']`, where my `nodejs user` is a user I wanted the home directory of. Worked like a charm (once I debugged the user creation resource, heh).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ohai's etc.passwd support is based on Ruby [Etc.passwd](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/etc/rdoc/Etc.html#method-c-passwd) which reads the `/etc/passwd` file.

This could be fine if your users are defined statically like this. If your server has users defined in a remote system like LDAP or NIS then those users will not be in /etc/passwd. You can list them with

```
`getent passwd`
```